# using DebugDiag

Tags: c#

How can I bind information in .dmp file with source code,i.e find line in source code
that caused the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to debug information files (.pdb) associated with the specific build being run when the dump was taken. If it was a build with full debugging then it will provide line level information (rather than "pdbonly", which only contains stack frame and method information --- albeit this can tell you a lot, often enough).

See John Robbin's recent blog entries about how pdb files are found: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/default.aspx

Comment: @Coulton ... and I'm not sure which article I was referring to: maybe *[Visual Studio Remote Debugging and PDB Files](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/visual-studio-remote-debugging-and-pdb-files)* or maybe *[PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know)* (latter updated last year with additional links).